# Insert one row from duplicate record in c>1 in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table i_table. I am inserting data from `x_ass_table into i_ass_table.`

`i_ass_table` has an index created against `ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER,EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE`
Now to avoid inserting duplicate data from a_table into i_table i have used count partition by like :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i_ass_table_pk ON 
i_ass_table(ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER,EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE)



insert into i_ass_table

SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY assignment_number, 
                                          effective_start_date,
                                          effective_end_date,
                                          effective_latest_change) AS c
        FROM   x_ass_table) t
WHERE  c =1
```

This is inserting the data correctly.

Now for data where c>1 i want only one row to be inserted but data to be inserted into i_Ass_table.
How can i insert one row from c>1 into i_ass_table ?

Comment: What do you mean by "insert one row from c> 1 into i_ass_table"? It would help if you could update your question to include sample input data, along with the data you're expecting to be inserted into your table.

Comment: @Boneist - c>1 means duplicate data ... that is one assignment number with duplicate/same effective start date end date and latest effective change

Comment: and you just want to pick one of those rows to insert? If so, change your `count()` to `row_number()` and add an order by clause after the `partition by`.

Comment: @Boneist -Thanks.. This worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use where clause as below

```
 where row_number() over (PARTITION BY assignment_number, 
                                      effective_start_date,
                                      effective_end_date,
                                      effective_latest_change) = 1
```

Comment: No, you can't; you can't filter using an analytic function in the same subquery it's defined in; you have to select the analytic function in the subquery and do the filtering in the outer query.

Comment: @P sabbineni -Thanks... This helped. I have posted the correct answer ablove

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select X.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY assignment_number, 
                                      effective_start_date,
                                      effective_end_date,
                                      effective_latest_change order by assignment_number) as RN 
           from  X_ass_table X)
           where RN=1)
```

Comment: if that works, I'll be very surprised - you're missing the ORDER BY clause inside the analytic function; you'll end up with `ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification`